# Plugin throws up 404 on front-end when when enqueuing style with filetime

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-style

I'm building a very simple plugin to add social media icons to each page on a site that I'm working on.

I was expecting the following code to enqueue a stylesheet on the front-end:

```
function myplugin_styles_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'myplugin-style', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/css/style.css', array(), filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/css/style.css' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_styles_scripts' );
```

On the front-end, I get the following error in the console:

> https://testing.local/app/public/wp-content/plugins/social-icons/css/style.css?ver=1583931475
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404

The directory and file exist within my plugin. What's causing this?

Comment: Is the first `plugin_dir_path()` just a typo in the question? Because that should be `plugin_dir_url()`.

Comment: Not a typo, my mistake. That works, but I'm getting a filetime error. Will post a separate question for that.

Comment: @SallyCJ please post your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the `404` error because you didn't provide the correct URL address of your CSS file.

And that's because of the *first* [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) below which outputs a *filesystem* directory path (e.g. `/home/user/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/`):

```php
wp_enqueue_style( 'myplugin-style', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/css/style.css', array(), filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/css/style.css' ) );
```

So you should instead use [`plugin_dir_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_url/) for getting the *URL* directory path for your plugin (e.g. `http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/`):

```php
wp_enqueue_style( 'myplugin-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/style.css', array(), filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/css/style.css' ) );
```

And note that both the functions include a trailing slash, so in the above code, I intentionally used `css/style.css` and not `/css/style.css`. Otherwise, the URL would contain `//css/style.css` (note the two slashes).

Comment: PS: You should also use just `css/style.css` with `plugin_dir_path()`, but I forgot to change that part in the answer. Sorry! :)

Comment: You rock, thank you 