# filemtime() warning when enqueuing style within plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-style

I'm receiving the following filemtime() warning:

> Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for
>   https://testing.local/wp-content/plugins/test-social-icons/css/style.css
>   in
>   /app/public/wp-content/plugins/zoo-social-icons/zoo-social-icons.php
>   on line 29

Here's how I'm enqueuing the stylesheet within my plugin:

```
function test_styles_scripts() {
   $dir = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
   wp_enqueue_style( 'test-style', $dir . 'css/style.css', array(), filemtime( $dir . 'css/style.css' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_styles_scripts' );
```

The stylesheet is correctly enqueuing. Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: Sally's comment [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/360448/plugin-throws-up-404-on-front-end-when-when-enqueuing-style-with-filetime) was that the **_first_** `plugin_dir_path()` needed to be `plugin_dir_url()`. The second one, for `filemtime()`, still needs to be `plugin_dir_path()`, because `filemtime()` requires a path, not a URL, but the browser requires a URL, which is what the first one is for.

Comment: Boom, that works! Thank you @JacobPeattie. Please post your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Restating the answer from @JacobPeattie in the comments above.

> filemtime() requires a path, not a URL

Therefore use `plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)`.

The full string for properly printing the cache-busting part of the version number at the end of the asset would be `filemtime( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__)`